# How can I draw a rectangle in image using rust language

Tags: rust

I'm trying to open an image, converting it into gray, and drawing a rectangle, then save it under another name, so, I'm using [image](https://github.com/image-rs/image) and [imageproc](https://github.com/image-rs/imageproc), and wrote the below code:

```rust
use image::{GenericImageView, FilterType, Rgb};
use imageproc::drawing::draw_hollow_rect_mut;
use imageproc::rect::Rect;

fn main() {
    let img = image::open("self.jpg").unwrap();

    let mut gray = img.grayscale();
    let white = Rgb([255u8, 255u8, 255u8]);

    draw_hollow_rect_mut(&mut gray, Rect::at(60, 10).of_size(20, 20), white);

    gray.save("gray.png").unwrap();
}
```

But I got the below error:

```
error[E0277]: the trait bound `image::dynimage::DynamicImage: image::image::GenericImage` is not satisfied
  --> src/main.rs:34:5
   |
34 |     draw_hollow_rect_mut(&mut gray, Rect::at(60, 10).of_size(20, 20), white);
   |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ the trait `image::image::GenericImage` is not implemented for `image::dynimage::DynamicImage`

   = note: required by `imageproc::drawing::rect::draw_hollow_rect_mut`
```

Comment: Seems to be a crate version incompatibility issue. The compiling error only happens to me under image-0.22.1 + imageproc-0.18.0. With a small modification, it compiles under image-0.21.0 + imageproc-0.18.0

Comment: @edwardw what modifications you did?

Comment: Change `white` to be type `Rgba` instead of `Rgb` as `draw_hollow_rect_mut` dictates.